# SQL Query to Insert Into without Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making a database for university parking application. I need a query that will insert into our PARKING_VIOLATION table if a VEHICLE in a SPACE is not validly parked. For example, they have an invalid parking pass. I want to turn this into an SQL job that repeats every ~5 minutes but after ticketing someone it does not detect duplicates.

My query

```
INSERT INTO PARKING_VIOLATION(Id, DateIssued, Description, Cost, VehicleRecieved)
    VALUES(NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Invalid Parking Pass','75',(
 SELECT
  VEHICLE.Id
FROM
  SPACE INNER JOIN VEHICLE ON (SPACE.OccupiedBy=VEHICLE.Id)
WHERE
  VEHICLE.PassId != SPACE.PassRequired));
```

I have tried things like REPLACE, INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS, or possibly need a way to compare the DateIssued to today.

Comment: What is the business rule you want to enforce, meaning, what constitutes a duplicate?

Comment: A duplicate would be if the same car is ticketed twice in one day.

Comment: REPLACE will only work if it can check for duplicates on the PRIMARY KEY or on a UNIQUE constraint. Your Id field looks like an auto_increment so that's going to be new every time and the DateIssued is not just the date it's a timestamp so that's also going to change every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, add another WHERE to the end to ensure the same Vehicle doesn't get booked twice in the same day.
Sorry about the time/date conversion but I'm used to Oracle's TRUNC and had to quickly do a search for MySQL version, I don't know why I assumed you're using MySQL though  :-D

```
INSERT INTO PARKING_VIOLATION(Id, DateIssued, Description, Cost, VehicleRecieved)
(SELECT NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Invalid Parking Pass','75', VEHICLE.Id
FROM SPACE 
INNER JOIN VEHICLE ON (SPACE.OccupiedBy=VEHICLE.Id)
WHERE VEHICLE.PassId <> SPACE.PassRequired)
WHERE VehicleRecieved NOT IN(
    SELECT VehicleReceived FROM PARKING_VIOLATION 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(DateIssued), '%e %b %Y') = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '%e %b %Y')
);
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error 'WHERE' is unexpected on the second WHERE.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, sorry about overlooking that. (needed to remove the VALUES bit)

Comment: Getting another syntax error on the second WHERE "LIMIT, ON, ORDER, or UNION expected"

Comment: Ok I see that I have spelled "Received" differently. Can you check the spelling of that in each case? If you still receive errors, try to take just the last SELECT query and run it alone. It should give you a list of vehicles that have been inserted into PARKING_VIOLATION table today, yes?

Comment: @jonsnow - at least make an effort to troubleshoot the code on your own.  Jeez - someone was nice enough to give you an answer and not only did you not try to figure it out, you didn't even uptick him.   +1 from me

Comment: @JohnMitchell I fixed the "recieved" problem. I can run the last query and get the list of vehicles inserted today but then what do I do with that query in order to prevent duplicates? Thank you so much.

Comment: Strange, I would have expected it to work. My only other thought would be to change the final WHERE to an AND and move it inside the previous brace. Like; `WHERE VEHICLE.PassId <> SPACE.PassRequired AND VehicleRecieved NOT IN( .... query the list of vehicles in violation today .... );`